# drag an image from uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

i am new to this iphone development, in an uiview i have a tableview, in each cell of tableview, i have an image. is it possible to drag or move an images which are in cells, to pos 1 from pos 2 as shown below.

```
|--------------------------|
|         |                |
|   ui    |table(image)    |
|         |view            |
|    1    | 2              |
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Are  you asking about reordering the rows by dragging them up or down?

Apple has a [guide on how to do this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html).

Comment: Now that progrmr has cleared up the image, it looks like you're trying to do something else.

Comment: hi schuur,
i want to pull the image inside a cell of a table view, and drop it across the view.

Comment: in a uiview i added table view, i reduced the width of table view in IB so that i table view in right side, as shown below
 
           |--------------------| i want to drag the 
 uiview    |                    |   image present in 
           | cell1 image1       | cell 1 and want to
 1         |--------------------| place it in pos1
           | cell2 image2       | but image1 shudnot be deleted
           |                    | in cell also

Comment: I understand what you want to do now, but I don't know how/if it can be done. I'm not even sure it's advisable to reduce the size of a table view to less than the full width of the device.